# How can I change .aws credentials path ? nodejs (aws-sdk)

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk-nodejs

To connect aws-sdk (nodejs) to aws I have to create credentials file then add accessKeyId and secretAccessKey at

> C:\Users{username}.aws\credentials

But I would like to change path .aws to somewhere else or create const variables of accessKeyId and secretAccessKey in js.

Can someone show me how can I change path ? or add accessKeyId and secretAccessKey somewhere inside js.

thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs here? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-json-file.html

Comment: Oh thanks so much @A.J.Alger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a JSON file containing your credentials like this

```
{
    "accessKeyId": " Your Access Key Id", 
    "secretAccessKey": "Your Secret Access Key",
    "region": "Your Region"
}
```

and save it. then give path of this JSON file using

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('File_Path/file_name.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to user AWS Environment variables:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html

Using this way you warantee AWS Runtime environment compatibility.